# How can I convert request data to json or dict format

Tags: python, django

From the client side, I receive some data by ajax post. The data type is json format.

```
function sendProjectBaseInfo() {

    prj = {
        id : $('#id').val(),
        email : $('#email').val(),
        title : $('#title').val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/prj/',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: prj,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result.Result)
        }
    });
}
```

After got the json data, I try to convert to json, or dict format.
To convert to json. I wrote like this:

```
import json

def post(self, request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            json_data = json.loads(request.data)
            print('Raw Data : %s'%request.body)
    return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

in case of above, I got 500 Internal server Error.

So I wrote like below to work around this error.

```
import json

def post(self, request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = json.dumps(request.data)
            print('Raw Data : %s'%request.body)
    return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

After all I got the same error. So I was look into the requested data.

```
import json

def post(self, request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print('Raw Data : %s'%request.body)
    return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

Print out is :

```
Raw Data : b'{"id":"1","email":"jason@test.co","title":"TEST"}'
```

How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 4):

**request** handles the **data** in the form of **bytes(data type)** so first we need to convert it into **string format**, after you can convert it into **json format**.

```
import json

def post(self,request):
   if request.is_ajax():
     if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = json.loads(str(request.body, encoding='utf-8'))
        print(json_data)
   return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

Answer (score 3):

you must be getting `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'` exception. (is it Python3?)

if yes, then
try this before `json.loads`: `.decode(encoding='UTF-8')`
this is because, the response body is of `byte` type, if notice small `b` in the beginning of output string

```
if request.method == 'POST':
       json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
       print('Raw Data : %s' % json_data)
       return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

Comment: @eachone: then print complete error trace here, otherwise we wont be able to figureout the problem.

Comment: Where can I get the error message? But, I have resolve this error. In the client side, data:JSON.stringfy(prj). your comment is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/prj/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: prj, #### YOUR ERROR IS HERE
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.Result)
    }
});
```

You will need to convert your data into string in your js.

Do the following in your js code

```
data: JSON.stringify(prj)
```